# LNK2019: extern symbol error

Tags: qt, popupwindow

I am using Qt and i want to show one window of configuration, and when the user push a button, show it the main window.

I think in that:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QApplication a(argc, argv);
 Dialog b;
 b.show();
 a.exec();
 MainWindow w;
 w.show();

 return a.exec();
}
```

but when i execute it, Qt tolds me:

`LNK2019 extern "public: virtual __thiscall Dialog::~Dialog(void)" (??1Dialog@@UAE@XZ)     sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _main`

and:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: símbolo externo "public: __thiscall Dialog::Dialog(class    QWidget *)" (??0Dialog@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _main
```

Anyone knows what I can do? If I delete the object Dialog, it works well. Its there any other form to have two windows?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Something is wrong with the project configuration or the `Dialog` class. Show its source.

Comment: Implement Dialog::~Dialog()